# Uno PlatformでInitializeComponentがコンパイルエラーになる

Tags: c#, xamarin

Uno Platformをちょっと触れてみようと思い[公式にある手順](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started.html#visual-studio)を参考にVisual Studio 2019で環境構築し、テンプレートからプロジェクトを作成しました。

しかし、テンプレートで作成されたSharedプロジェクトにある[MainPage.xaml.cs]を開くと、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
'MainPage' に 'InitializeComponent' の定義が含まれておらず、型 'MainPage' の最初の引数を 受け付けるアクセス可能な拡張メソッド 'InitializeComponent' が見つかりませんでした。using ディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が不足していないことを確認してください
```

開発環境の要件は満たしており、ビルドすれば実行されますがエラーが表示される原因がわかりません。
公式の手順以外に何か必要なものがあったりしたら、どなたかご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: 問題無いのかもしれませんよ。この記事 [Uno Platform を始めよう](https://rksoftware.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/01/19/200022) の「■ 実行」の直前のスクリーンショットに同様の現象が記述されています。

Comment: @kunif さんありがとうございます。エラーは出るけど問題ないんですね…ページが増えるたびにエラーも増えて開発しづらそうですね